# Sharing Ad Revenue among Users of a Multisite in a Collaborative Model?

Tags: plugins, multisite, adsense, ads, community

Is anyone aware of some functionality to share the revenue among the users of a Multisite?

A multisite lets other people create and mainatain their own blogs. The Multisite owner  should able to share some percentage, say N% (like 20%) of revenue on the sub-sites hosted.

**Example:**

> You are that owner of a Multisite on
>   xyz.com and offer blogs to your
>   "friends" User1, User2 and so on.
>   User1 and User2 use adsense or adbrite
>   on their blog. The functionality would
>   ensure that you get 20% from the
>   revenue they earn.

I have seen the [author-advertising-plugin (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/author-advertising-plugin) which shares the revenue within a single site among multiple authors. I do not know if it supports Multisite because for me it would be better. If I have the possibility to share the revenue Multisite-wide. I would like to know If that plugin suits perfectly to Multisite installation or not.

Comment: I edited the question a bit to make it more clear and to point to points which are open. Sorry for the crazy sounding language at the end.

Answer (score 3):

This plugin does it: http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/ad-sharing (it is a paid membership site).

Comment: *@Ulrich Sossou:* - Nice!

Comment: Thanks for recommending this plugin  ! I will try it when ever I get ability to register an account at WPMUDev .

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion that plugin is useless.  The only way that I see to do this is for the Admin (you) to have the ad accounts and for you to distribute the funds to each respective blogger.  The problem arises when you have more than one advertising network (Sixapart, Adify, Adsense...) and more than one revenue metric (eg. CPM, CPC, CPA & Sponsorship).  In that case it's an accounting nightmare to affectively quantify each bloggers share.

If your revenue is primarily CPM display ads then you should measure each authors traffic level and distribute the revenue accordingly.

If you are using Adsense only, then you can set up different channels for each author and distribute the money each channel earns.

I can't believe that Wordpress doesn't have a way to track the amount of traffic each author gets but this can be over come in Analytics.

**EDIT:** *To clarify, I was calling the plugin mentioned in the question "useless."  Really it's not useless, but it has such a narrow use that I can't conceive anyone that would actually find it useful.  The WPMUdev plugin that was mentioned after I posted this answer is also very specific.  It allows you to run your own ads in tandum with your user's ads.  You are not actually sharing the revenue, you are sharing ad inventory and allowing them to sell their own and keep that money while you keep the money generated by your own inventory.*

Comment: Wordpress has no stats in core. Nor does it provide a framework for ads. Believe it or not :)

Comment: matt, if when you say 'that plugin' you mean the one Ulrich Sossou mentioned, please delete your answer and post it as a comment on Ulrich's answer. Answer posts are for exactly that - answers. Using an Answer post to respond to another Answer is not the proper usage. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt
Thanks for your reply ! I will definitely follow your Instructions.
By the way would you be please mention the plugin name which you said useless. Author-advertising-plugin (Wordpress Plugin) or
the plugin mentioned by Ulrich Sossou ?

Comment: @tnorthcutt,  I didn't mean Ulrich's answer because I posted my answer before he posted his answer.  I was referring to the plugin in the question.

Comment: @hakre I do believe it.  I guess I should have said that I'm annoyed by the lack of this core functionality or plugin.  ;)  Tracking the pageviews that each author on the site gets is of central importance to anyone that uses display ads that are monetized on CPM.  Not to mention, it is imho the most important metric to evaluate author performance.

Comment: @user391 I have used the WPMUdev plugin but it didn't suit my needs.  If you want to try it out before you buy an $80 a month membership to the site let me know and I can give you a copy (it's license under GNU General Public License so I think I'm allowed to do this, if not someone chime in).  Personally I was not very happy with my WPMUdev membership and one of the reasons was that I felt they oversold their plugins with descriptions that are not representative of the actual functions and limitations.  If you are interested just let me know how to email you.

Comment: @matt ahh, that makes sense now. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Today I went trough the plugin repository and found these two plugins.I think these plugins best suits  for the Multisite  Ad-sharing

[Adsense revenue sharing](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adsense-revenue-sharing/) : Here we can share the revenue using adsense publisher Ids.Some Phpbb forum hosting platforms,wikidot etc web-services follow the similar procedure.They share revenue with with their sub-site user displaying ads with certain Time Intervals .This wordpress plugin is not updated for more than 2 years .
But this plugin have some Nice features

- Site Admins can share revenue based
  on Hits.
- Need to configure the plugin Sub-site wise .We Can manage site wide if we use any
  Multi-site manager plugins

[Advertising Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advertising-manager) :This plugin may be useful for sharing among Authors .But not best suitable for Multi-site installation as mentioned in this question

I hope some one would create plugin for this in the future

Thanks!